# Fetch request to Swagger API keeps returning CORS error even in Try it out editor

Tags: reactjs, cors, swagger, vite

I'm working on an app made in React (Vite) and I'm currently trying to access a third party Swagger API that was given to me to make a fetch request using react-query. My issue is that no matter how much I play around with my proxy or request headers I keep getting either 401 Unauthorized or CORS error.

This is how my current request looks like:

```
const useFetchItems = ({ query, params, token }) => {
  const fetchUrl = `/api${query}${params}`;

  return useQuery(query, async () => {
    console.log('URL:', fetchUrl, 'TOKEN:', token);
    const response = await fetch(fetchUrl, {

      headers: {
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      method: "GET",
    });
    console.log(response)
    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error("An error has occured.");
    }
    return response.json();
  });
};

export default useFetchItems;
```

I'm passing through the authorization token I received from Firebase authentication and despite that whenever I'm using proxy I get 401 unauthorized error. The issue isn't with the way my token var is getting passed as I'm getting the same error when I hardcode the token. I also tried setting up `mode: no-cors` and small things like that, doesn't work.

By logging out the response I get, I can tell that my proxy is working fine. This is how I set it up in my vite.config file:

```
const url= 'http://redacted.example.api/v1/'

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  server: {
    proxy: {
      "/api": {
        target: url,
        changeOrigin: true,
        secure: false,
        rewrite: (path) => path.replace(/^\/api/, ""),
      },
    },
  },
});
```

Whenever I try using the api url without proxy, I get the CORS error. **The CORS error also happens when I try out any API request with the Try it out editor**. The fact that my request works fine in Postman makes me think the issue lies with CORS, but how can I fix it on my end if I have no  influence over the API. Should I contact the API owners (it is an API owned by a company I'm applying to) or is this someone that can be circumvented from my side?